# Cocoa: Return to previous active application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

is there a way to capture application that was previously active, before my application was brought to front by user?

I've tried to this in applicationWillBecomeActive: delegate method, but my application is already mark as active.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Register for the [NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW98) notification in NSWorkspace. This will give you an NSRunningApplication instance of what was deactivated.